# Touch events are not handled on iPhone Safari when page scrolled

Tags: javascript, touch, mobile-safari, touch-event

On Safari on an iPhone, if you fast scroll the page, the **white box** events are not handled until the scrolling stops.

(To see this bug, you need to scroll the page by swiping and try touching the white box while the page is still scrolling. To see the expected behavior, try touching it without the page scrolling.)

```js
const fix = document.querySelector('.fix')
const text = document.querySelector('.handle')

fix.addEventListener('touchstart', handle)
fix.addEventListener('touchend', handle)
fix.addEventListener('mousedown', handle)
fix.addEventListener('touchmove', handle)

function handle(e){
  text.innerText  = e.type
  console.log(e)
}
```

```css
.scroll{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000vh;
  background: rgb(226,252,193);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(226,252,193,1) 0%, rgba(182,251,176,1) 3%, rgba(204,128,151,1) 49%, rgba(134,133,189,1) 75%, rgba(71,153,222,1) 98%, rgba(0,204,247,1) 100%);
}
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.fix{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.handle{
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; 
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll"></section>
<div class="fix">
  <p class="handle"></p>
</div>
```

[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/-greg-/full/MWyjJNK)

Comment: Is this working fine on other devices?

Comment: I test on android - its working fine

Comment: but in IOS is not working

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Safari bug, I can replicate the "issue" on my OnePlus 6 using Firefox and Chrome. The first touch while the scroll is ongoing stops it, seems like a thing tied to the phone's OS.

Comment: this is Safari bug. all browsers on iPhone has safari engine

Comment: firefox & chrome on ios are just wrappers of safari :), they don't use there actually engine